# <style> in HTML works, but not as CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm right now kinda confused... I want to make a small HP and already failing adding defined CSS tag in my DIV. If I define the CSS in the php file, the DIV uses it correctly but if I try the same code in the seperate CSS file, it only applies the body background.

I hope you can help me in this case.

This is it how it looks like:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.index_bg 
{
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
};

#index_div
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
 width:2000px;
 height:2000px;
 max-width:80vw;
 max-height:80vh;
 margin:10vh auto 10vh auto; 
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>3D Solutions</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body class="index_bg">


    <div id="index_div"> 

    Lorem Ipsum.

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an erroneous semicolon in your css

```
.index_bg 
{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}; <-- remove this
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.index_bg 
 {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
 };
```

to

```
.index_bg 
{
   background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this......

```
   .index_bg 
    {
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
    }

    #index_div
    {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        width:2000px;
        height:2000px;
        max-width:80vw;
        max-height:80vh;
        margin:10vh auto 10vh auto; 
    }
```

Don't put a semicolon`;` after closing brace `}`

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.index_bg 
{
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

#index_div
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
 width:2000px;
 height:2000px;
 max-width:80vw;
 max-height:80vh;
 margin:10vh auto 10vh auto; 
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>3D Solutions</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body class="index_bg">


    <div id="index_div"> 

    Lorem Ipsum.

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```